# Migration:method references not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;


class CreatePhoneNumbersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('phone_numbers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('contact_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I what to connect the table, but phpstorm is showing me that **references metod not found in Illuminate\Support\Flunet.**
i have no idea  why i don't have this method, and **i don't know what means unsignedInteger?**

Comment: seems you haven't defined user_id in migration and directly creation foreign reference.

Comment: i changed user_id to contact_id but it is the same

Comment: `$table->unsignedInteger('contact_id');` is the same as `$table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned();` Does that still give the same error? Do you have ide-helper installed?

Comment: i add ide-helper and do as you told me and same, references metod not found